# How to combine table 2 sheets (ข้อมูลตัวอย่าง1 and ข้อมูลตัวอย่าง2) to new table 1 sheet (Use VLOOKUP formula with multiple condition)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup, microsoft-excel-365, microsoft-excel-2019

I have data in Excel file to combine table 2 sheets (Have data with web : https://www.contextures.com/xlSampleData01.html)

How to combine table 2 sheets **(ข้อมูลตัวอย่าง1 and ข้อมูลตัวอย่าง2)** to new table 1 sheet (Use VLOOKUP formula with multiple condition) without PivotTable ?

Image to describe How to combine table 2 sheets **(ข้อมูลตัวอย่าง1 and ข้อมูลตัวอย่าง2)** to new table 1 sheet : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b1Ol.png

Because I learn with web https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/02/12/vlookup-multiple-sheets-excel-examples/ and https://trumpexcel.com/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria/ and try to use VLOOKUP formula with single condition with example **=VLOOKUP(A2, 'ข้อมูลตัวอย่าง2-1'!$A$2:$D$4, 4, FALSE)** to display at **ข้อมูลรูปแบบรวมเป็นตารางเดียว2** Sheet (Yellow sheet tab) and can use VLOOKUP formula with single condition normally but try to use VLOOKUP formula with multiple condition with example **=VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2, ข้อมูลตัวอย่าง2!$A$2:$D$41, 4, FALSE)** to display at **ข้อมูลรูปแบบรวมเป็นตารางเดียว3** Sheet (Orange sheet tab) to cannot use VLOOKUP formula with multiple condition normally (have **#N/A** value instead VLOOKUP value) with image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uji6M.png

Example excel file with Link : https://github.com/doanga2007/doanga2007.github.io/raw/master/CombineTable2Sheet2.xlsx

Comment: Convert Sheet name in English!!

Comment: @RajeshS I convert sheet name in English and post answer to combine table 2 sheets to new table 1 sheet with formula.

Comment: That's good,, please remove the LINK from LAST Comments, since you have used the same PAGE/QUESTION link you are working with !!

Comment: @RajeshS OK , I remove the link from last comment already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good News :** I fix problem with solution and credit to fix problem :  https://www.snasui.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17680

1. Use formula in example E2 **=INDEX(Sampledata2!D$2:D$41,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sampledata2!A$2:A$41=A2)*(Sampledata2!B$2:B$41=B2)*(Sampledata2!C$2:C$41=C2),),))**

**Image link to describe use formula in example E2** because you need at least 10 reputation to post images : https://i.stack.imgur.com/coJFT.png

2. I can to combine table 2 sheets to new table 1 sheet with formula.

**Excel file to fix problem link with Sheet name in English :** https://github.com/doanga2007/doanga2007.github.io/raw/master/CombineTable2Sheet3.xlsx

Comment: Share some sample Screen shot,, will help you to justify the method you have used so far, will attract readers and you may get UP votes too ☺

Comment: @RajeshS I add image link to describe use formula in example E2 already.

Comment: I don't think the facebook-link is helpful.

Comment: @Mast I delete facebook-link and remain credit to fix problem 1 link to helpful.